# 18.04.4 Fails to shutdown

Tags: 18.04, gnome, shutdown, thinkpad

Laptop: Thinkpad E485, 32GB RAM, Ryzen 3 2200U with vega graphics. Kernel 5.3.0-53-generic
Symptoms: Fails to shut down. Both from gui and `shutdown -h now` results in black screen, unresponsive keyboard, but the power light stays on. The laptop never truly shuts down, and it results in battery being discharged to 0%.

Answer (score 1):

A bug has been filled as [#1880041](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta-hwe/+bug/1880041)

Please pass by and click "It affects me too" so it gets more attention

Answer (score 0):

The issue passed after kernel upgrade to 5.6.14 using the `ukuu` tool:

I had problems installing `ukuu` from the provided PPA, so I had to build it from source. I used the instructions posted on [the ukuu git repository page](https://github.com/teejee2008/ukuu).

```bsh
sudo apt-get install libgee-0.8-dev libjson-glib-dev libvte-2.91-dev valac
git clone https://github.com/teejee2008/ukuu.git
cd ukuu
make all
```

This step produces a lot of warnings, or at least it did on my laptop, but those are not really important, the resulting binary worked fine.

```bsh
sudo make install
```

After the last step just run the `ukuu-gtk` binary and install selected kernel. I chose 5.6.14, because it was the latest one at the time of writing this answer. The shutdown problems went away, there may be some incompatibilities, but you have to test it for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

**2020-06-18 edit**

[Kernel 5.3.0-59 fixes the issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta-hwe/+bug/1880041/comments/60). I strongly recommend you to update your install and only use kernels from official repositories rather than ones suggested by others that were probably never tested with the rest of your software and won't get any updates.

---

**Original answer**

Have you tried booting with an older version of the kernel? See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/82145) for instructions on how to do so.

If no other version than 5.3.0-53 is installed, try installing 5.3.0-51 (it does solve the issue on my computer)

```
sudo apt install linux-image-5.3.0-51-generic linux-headers-5.3.0-51-generic
```

Until you upgrade to 20.04 or 18.04.5 ships with kernel 5.4 (and assuming it does fix the issue), I advice you to stick with 5.3.0-51.

In order to force your computer to boot on this kernel version, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1097697) from the same thread.

Obviously, if a new version of kernel 5.3 gets released, try if it fixes the issue and then set `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` to boot on the newest kernel.

Hopes it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on T495 AMD Ryzen 7 PRO 3700U. I manage to solve it on 5.3.0-53 by installing AMD drivers from here https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-10

I hope this solves the issue for you as well :)